# How to produce .npy features correctly in sound_classification_ml_production?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, librosa

I ran the github repo code [sound_classification_ml_production](https://github.com/jsalbert/sound_classification_ml_production/blob/main/notebooks/UrbanSound8k_machine_learning.ipynb) and got good accuracy, but found that .npy features are pre produced by author. So I want produce my own .npy and add code blow:

```
# FeatureExtractor class including librosa audio processing functions
class FeatureExtractor:

...


def compute_save_features(self, 
                    mode='mfcc', 
                    sample_rate=22050,
                    n_fft=2048,
                    hop_length=512,
                    n_mfcc=40,
                    output_path='features',
                    deltas=False
                    ):
    dataset_features = []
    max_pad = self._compute_max_pad_length(self.max_audio_duration, 
                                           sample_rate=sample_rate, 
                                           n_fft=n_fft,
                                           hop_length=hop_length)
    print('Max Padding = ', max_pad)
    
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        print('Creating output folder: ', output_path)
        os.makedirs(output_path)
    else:
        print('Output folder already existed')
        
    print('Saving features in ', output_path)
    i = 0
    t = time.time()
    
    features_path = []
    for relative_filepath in self.dataset_df['filepath']:
        filepath = base_path + relative_filepath;
        print('compute_save_features, filepath = ' + str(filepath))

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('{} files processed in {}s'.format(i, time.time() - t))

        print('compute_save_features, librosa.load, filepath = ' + str(filepath))
        audio_file, sample_rate = librosa.load(filepath, sr=sample_rate, res_type='kaiser_fast')
        if mode == 'mfcc':
            audio_features = self.compute_mfcc(audio_file, sample_rate, n_fft, hop_length, n_mfcc, deltas)  
        elif mode == 'stft':
            audio_features = self.compute_stft(audio_file, sample_rate, n_fft, hop_length)
        elif mode == 'mel-spectogram':
            audio_features = self.compute_mel_spectogram(audio_file, sample_rate, n_fft, hop_length)
        
        audio_features = np.pad(audio_features, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, max_pad - audio_features.shape[1])))
        print('compute_save_features, audio_features = ' + str(type(audio_features)) + ', ' + str(audio_features))

        # here I add code and save audio_features to my .npy
        npy_path = os.path.join(output_path, filepath.split('/')[-1].replace('wav', 'npy'))
        print('compute_save_features, npy_path = ' + str(npy_path))
        np.save(npy_path, audio_features)
        
        ...

fe = FeatureExtractor(base_path + 'UrbanSound8K/metadata/UrbanSound8K.csv')

dataset_df = fe.compute_save_features(mode='mfcc', n_mfcc=13, output_path=base_path + 'my_features_mfcc', deltas=True)

...
```

after compared with author's origin .npy, there is so many diffs:

[image]

Please anyone could tell me that how to produce exactly the same .npy features as in repo code show, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras layers are initialized randomly. To reproduce the same result you have to set the same seed. If you don't have a seed value - you have no chance to reproduce.

Comment: ok, got it, thank you.   But I notice that my .npy shape is (39, 174), while orgin .npy shape is (39, 174, 1). could you tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: You are saving using np.save, original is using PIL. I didn't work with PIL, so I can not help